# Coloring areas of map in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, but I know C# very well.
I am working on a game similar to eu4.
When area is conquered, it should change color.
I have no idea how to do it, or what to search in the internet for a solution.

Here is the map:
[image]
(The borders separate the areas)

Any help please?

Comment: You need to give us some more information, we need to know what this "area" is before we can tell you how to change its color. How have you set up the map?

Comment: What you are asking is precisely what the OP is asking, Fredrik.   It's a perfectly good (if basic) question.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, you **just have sprites** for each "country".

(So, in the dark color.)

Simply turn them on or off as you wish. That's all there is to it.

Another approach is you could learn how to make and use a typical **"flood fill algorithm"**.  But that is far beyond the scope of this question and is a general computer science issue.  (You might look on, say, gamedev for starter tips on this. Additionally you'll have to become expert at generating textures dynamically in Unity.)

Comment: I have the full map. Is what I need to do is to create sprites for each area?

Comment: Correct - do that.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Check EU4 and CK2 map files. It might give you many ideas how to handle grand strategy maps.

You got some work to do to achieve this. But basically, there is a .bmp file in game files which every province is painted with a unique color. Here is an example of small portion which consist Italy:

[image: see all provinces are painted with different color]

Once you've done that, you will need some sort of data file (.csv in eu4's case) that includes which color includes which province, which provinces are neighboring, etc... In EU4, color info and adjadency info are in seperate files, but of course you're free to approach however you want.

Once you are done with "Data" part, you will need an algorithm that scans these files and distinguish each province in seperate game objects. Mainly, you must write a method that removes every color in an image except a certain one, instantiate it to the map and repeat process for each province. And you're done.

Edit: You can, of course, do these manually. But automated process is always better especially when you a lot of povinces to sepearate. Also making tweaks in map will be much easier that way, or you'll have a hard time recreating every single sprite for even small changes.

Another advantage is, you can easily add different mapmodes like heightmap, rivermap or such...

Answer (score 0):

As your question doesn't give much in terms of your structure it's hard to give you examples.

The most straightforward for you probably is to separate your map into nodes (your bordered areas) and display them all as unique gameObjects. You can then access things like their Renderer to give them different colour.

We can give much better answers if you give us more information on how your data/graphics are structured.